# Trouble setting a falling msw (mock-service-worker) and get it to throw

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, msw

The component I got looks like this so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import { MagnifyingGlass } from 'icons'

import styles from './SearchBox.module.css'

function SearchBox({ setPhotos }) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  const handleTyping = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSearchTerm(event.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (searchTerm === '') {
      return null
    }

    try {
      const restURL = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
      }&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1'&text=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`
      const { data } = await Axios.get(restURL)
      const fetchedPhotos = data.photos.photo
      setPhotos(fetchedPhotos)
      setSearchTerm('')
    } catch (error) {
      if (!Axios.isCancel(error)) {
        throw error
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <form action="none">
        <input
          aria-label="Search Flickr"
          placeholder="What are you looking for?"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleTyping}
        />
        <button type="submit" aria-label="Submit search" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          <MagnifyingGlass />
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}

export default SearchBox
```

My attempt to TDD looks like this

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { rest } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'

import SearchBox from '.'

const fakeServer = setupServer(
  rest.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search', (req, res, ctx) =>
    res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ photos: { photo: [1, 2, 3] } }))
  )
)

beforeAll(() => fakeServer.listen())
afterEach(() => fakeServer.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => fakeServer.close())

// .. some other test using the fakeServer

test('throws an error if server error', async () => {
  fakeServer.resetHandlers()
  fakeServer.close()
  const fakeFailingServer = setupServer(
    rest.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search', (req, res, ctx) =>
      res(
        ctx.status(500),
        ctx.json({
          errorMessage: `Error! Something went terribly wrong!`,
        })
      )
    )
  )
  fakeFailingServer.listen()

  const fakeSetPhotos = jest.fn(() => {})
  const { getByRole } = render(<SearchBox setPhotos={fakeSetPhotos} />)

  const inputField = getByRole('textbox', { name: /search flickr/i })
  const submitButton = getByRole('button', { name: /submit search/i })

  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(() => {
      userEvent.type(inputField, 'Finding Walley')
      fireEvent.click(submitButton)
    }).toThrow()
  )

  fakeFailingServer.resetHandlers()
  fakeFailingServer.close()
})
```

But it just hangs... So could use a little guidance on what I'm doing wrong here ‍♂️

Comment: Hi! I found this question because I have exactly the same issue! Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Can't recall - you can take a look at https://github.com/Norfeldt/react-kitchen-sink